# How to traverse linked records in orientdb using fetch plans?

Tags: nosql, orientdb, graph-databases

I created a hierarchical graph  with 2 classes (Class A and Class B). Class A has embedded property "address" which links to class B. I'm trying to traverse both graphs to print the data using following queries, but it only returned class A data.
**select name from A fetchplan address:-1;
select name from A fetchplan *:-1;**

[image: Class A and class B]

[image: Graphs]

Could please tell me why class B graph data is not shown? how to traverse both classes ?

Comment: Hi, did you connect vertices through link or edge? What version are you using? Thx

Comment: Thankyou for your reply. I connected vertices through edge and connected classes through EMBEDDED link. If I apply search query on parent class "select * from classA" it doesn't return me classB results which are linked as EMBEDDED record in classA. 

I'm using version 2.2.31